# Application enter in a "wait status" while HttpRequest operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, request, httprequest, async-await

I'm doing an HttpRequest to an Url that returns me an xml content. So I try to make an asynchronous request but during this request the application is stopped (pause) and it seems that it cannot get a response (the url inside a browser works perfectly and it returns what I expected).

Here is my code:

```
public static async Task<String> getResponse(String url)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage request = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    String stream = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return stream;
}
```

and I take this with:

```
String response = UtilityClass.getResponse(requestUrl).Result;
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you get no response? Is the response just empty? Does it thrown an exception or something? What status code do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happends here is a deadlock. Without too much information i see you're blocking on an asynchronous operation when calling

```
string response = UtilityClass.getResponse(requestUrl).Result
```

What happends is when you `await` inside `getResponse`, the `TaskAwaitable` being generated captures your [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) in order to marshal the continuation back on to the same context in which it was called. But, when it trys to marshal work bacl to the captured context it cant, because `Result` is blocking the thread. This is why you should [`never block on async code`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). This can be fixed by using [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which tells the `TaskAwaitable` not to marshal the continuation back and simply execute on the current thread that invoked it:

```
public static async Task<String> getResponse(String url)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage request = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    String stream = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return stream;
}
```

Another solution, which is better IMO, is to use the `async` method properly and `await` on it, instead of block:

```
string response = await UtilityClass.getResponse(requestUrl)
```

That would require you to add the `async` keyword to the calling method. If you cant, maybe a synchronous http request might be the better solution.

**Edit**

To quote @EricLippert comment which makes this easier to understand:

> The key thing to understand here is that `result = task.Result;` means **do nothing else until the result is available**, and `result = await task`; means **do something else until the result is available**. Both turn a `Task<string>` into a string, but one blocks and the other does not

There are many good posts explaining the fundamental s of async/await:

1. [`Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)
2. [`Asynchrony in C# 5 Series (Eric Lippert)`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx)
3. [`Async Await Intro (Stephan Cleary)`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)
4. [`Async Await FAQ`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx)

Comment: The ".Result" that I added is to get the string result from the method getResponse because it returns a Task<String> and I want to get the String.. sorry maybe I'm a little bit confuse about it.
I didn't found an example with synchronous http request :/ only asynchronous....

Comment: When you call the `Result` property of a `Task` it blocks as it did if you were using a synchronous request. Add `ConfigureAwait(false)` as i showed in my example

Comment: Yes thank you, I added the ConfigureAwait(false) and the code works, but then how I can get the response stream without the .Result? I call the getResponse method that it works and returns the Task<String>, how can I get the String from this returned task?

Comment: If you `await getResponse` then the string will be unwrapped for you from the `Task`. If not, use the Result property (which will block but not deadlock because you used ConfigureAwait)

Comment: @Pame1692: The key thing to understand here is that `result = task.Result;`  means **do nothing else until the result is available**, and `result = await task;` means **do something else until the result is available**. Both turn a `Task<string>` into a `string`, but one blocks and the other does not.